# Removing data posted to iframe and submit new data in php form

Tags: php, html, forms, iframe

I have been working on displaying a url, submitted from a form, in an iframe on the same page. I had everything working fine, except the page would refresh to the top. So I used target="iframe" to stop this from occuring. Now I cannot get new url's to show to the iframe, but when I refresh my page, an old url that was submitted keeps showing up. How to I get the content of the iframe to accept the a newly submitted URL? The lociation of the form and iframe is http://www.4mobilesites.com  and the code that I am using is:

```
<div class="mobile-logo">
<H2>How does your website look on a Mobile Device?</h2>
<?php 
$keyurl = $_POST['siteurl'];
?>

<form method="post" target="frame">
Enter your website's URL: <input type="text" name="siteurl" value="http://" size="50"><br>
<input type="submit" value="VIEW">
</form><br>
<a name="iframe-1"></a>
<div class="theiframewrap"><iframe name="frame" class="theiframeid" src="<?php echo "$keyurl"; ?>" id="frame"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Comment: sounds like its jut being cached

Comment: When you submit another url, shouldn't it replace the old url? or is there a way to clear the old url?